# How to do cross platform build for Linux target on Windows build system without even WSL

Tags: linux, windows, cmake, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I am doing some POC where I need to build for Linux target on Windows build system without even WSL. So what I want to do is below.

1. Build for Linux target on Windows build system
2. Copy the build executable to Linux/ Ubuntu machines and it should be able to run.

I know cmake supports cross-platform builds. However, I could not find out where I would get Linux-related libraries/so (Linux environment) to build my target.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a cross-compiler, and your easiest method by far will be to use WSL.  I don't use Windows so can't give any more specific advice, but be aware you're also going to have to deal with things like libc compatibility.

Comment: You take your linux distribution, copy the contents of `/` over to Windows (you only need libraries and headers, so you can probably limit yourself to `/usr/{lib,include}`, `/{lib,include}`). Then you take Clang (the regular Windows version) and pass `--target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` (or whatever `clang++ --version` prints on that Linux) and `--sysroot=path/to/files` (with a path to the copied `/`).